# Excel count and sort rows satisfying multiple criteria across columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that resembles something like the following:

```
+----+------+------+--+------+------+
| A  |  B   |  C   | D|  E   |  F   |
+----+------+------+--+------+------+
| T1 |      | TRUE |  |      |      |  
| T2 | TRUE |      |  |      |      |  
| T3 |      | TRUE |  | TRUE |      |  
| T4 | TRUE | TRUE |  |      |      |  
| T5 |      |      |  |      | TRUE |  
+----+------+------+--+------+------+
```

I want to rearrange rows according to the decreasing number of multiple activities each T supports i.e. more TRUE values a T has across columns, it comes at the top along with the count of TRUEs for each row.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Add a helper column that counts the number of TRUEs and sort on that.

Comment: Ah that's a good idea